# Bash: Redirect command output to STDOUT and variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

In a Bash script, I need to redirect the output of a command to a variable, while also streaming unbuffered output to the terminal.

I've tried this:

```
output=$(command 2>&1 | tee "$(tty)")
```

but this doesn't output anything to the terminal.

I've also tried

```
mytty=$(tty)
output=$(command 2>&1 | tee $mytty)
```

This gives me the error "tee: /dev/tty1: Permission denied".

The current OS is OpenSUSE 15.0 and I do not have sudo/root rights.

Comment: here is an answer that works for bash & zsh https://serverfault.com/a/989827/951158

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
... | tee /dev/tty
```

Like:

```
output=$( command 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty )
```

The command `tty` doesn't work inside a pipe:

```
$ echo $(tty)           # or (a lot better) simply:  tty
/dev/pts/4

$ echo aa | echo $(tty)
not a tty
```

Which means that the right side of a pipe is not connected to a tty.

Comment: Thank you. That works exactly the way I needed it.